# How to cache over multiple nodes for scalability

Tags: caching, scalability

FYI - I am a new member, fairly new programmer, and this is my first post on stackoverflow.

For my web apps I've been writing my own data caching layer; In doing so the app has been set up to fetch data from the database only when not found in cache. And over time the app drops stale data from cache in an effort to minimize the amount of data held in RAM. This has worked well for me to limit the number of read-only requests made to the database server, provided my webapp resides on a single server. Now I am thinking about load balancing my webapp over many nodes and I would like to keep the caching implementation as is. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to keep the different webapp nodes cache layers in sync.

The problem scenario is probably a typical one:

1. Person A reads version #1 of record #1 on node #1; cache is updated on node #1.
2. Person B reads version #1 of record #1 on node #2; cache is updated on node #2.
3. Person A updates record #1 on node #1;

   - data is not read from db since it's in cache.
   - cache is updated with version #2 of record #1.
   - version #2 data-write is sent to db.
4. Person B reads record #1 on node #2;

   - data is not read from db since it's in cache resulting in version #1, which is now outdated.

So there's a few ideas that come to mind.

1. I could drop caching and every read/write comes from db (obviously not ok with me).
2. I could implement some form of consistent hashing. i.e. I could send all record #1 items to node # 1. However I found there's data that needs to be shared across each node, such as user profile data (i.e. when record #1 is updated then the users profile needs to be updated too, so that needs to get into the other nodes caches as well leaving me with the same problem for profile records).
3. I could use consistent hashing for records and somehow split out the user data such that that data layer is not cached (still not ideal).
4. I could learn erlang and start sending messages between cache layers, however I've tried my hand at erlang it never really took (probably the ideal technical solution, but I'd rather not learn erlang - lol).

So this is the first time I've given this much thought. Any well known strategies that a hermit-like hobby programmer like me should know? Ideas, Solutions?

Notes:
- My primary language is Clojure, though that is not necessarily relevant to the problem at hand.
- I am already using NoSQL dbs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in implementing your own caching solution and want to keep nodes in sync, than you probably want to add some external cache invalidation interface to your system.

For example if your NoSQL database supports post-update hooks it can issue *multicast UDP* command to all nodes that some value is not valid anymore. Alternatively you can use some kind of message queue for this (like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)), but that probably would be overkill.

Since Clojure is a JVM-based language you can just use some existing JVM caching solution, like [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/). If you are not implementing this caching system for educational purposes, doing so can save you a lots of time and efforts.

By the way learning Erlang is a great combination of fun and useful experience. I never regret that I spent some part of my life getting used to it. It will definitively pay off in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement caching in your application instead of going for a distributed cache, looks like there is one work-around.

Maintain a table which contains the records of IPs of all the nodes related to that particular service. i.e, we register a particular node while it is start-up. Whenever a particular node gets the update request, it asks other nodes to invalidate their cache, using these records.

However one issue with this approach is that, when a node goes down and it is not deregistered from the database, its update fails. If we write fail-safe logic, it might lead to inconsistency in the data.

Perodic reporting of health to the database by each node should be helpful in determining the validity. This overhead has to be appropriately balanced based on how frequenctly the data get updated.

Correct me if I am wrong or if there are any gaps. TIA